# Flutter pass data from listview to other Screen

Tags: flutter

What is easiest way to pass data from listTile to SecondScrean both listTile  and SecondScrean  is at one mypage.dart

```
onTap: () {
        Navigator.push(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(
             builder: (context) => DetailScreen(),
          ),
       );
       {print(data[index].name);}  //How pass name and surname to details
},


class DetailScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('DetailScreen'),
      ),
      body: Padding(
        child: Text('display name from listTile here'),
        child: Text('display surname from listTile here'),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

please try this

```
onTap: () {
        Navigator.push(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(
             builder: (context) => DetailScreen(data[index].name),
          ),
       );
       {print(data[index].name);}  //How pass name and surname to details
},


class DetailScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  String name;
  DetailScreen(this.name);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('DetailScreen'),
      ),
      body: Padding(
        child: Text('display $name from listTile here'),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: you can pass class object as well as